# issue with twitter bootstrap wowslider jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I designed a page using twitter bootstrap and add a image slider(wowslider) in it,
now the problem is wowslider not transforming properly.
Hear is the link...

http://infotechsam.99k.org/quiz.php

When i remove this from header part

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

the slider working properly..

Any solution for this problem without removing the bootstrap.css link?
My full source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">
    <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images" id="slider"><ul>
<li><img src="data1/images/img1.jpg" alt="ads" title="ads" id="wows1_0"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/img2.jpg" alt="debug" title="debug" id="wows1_1"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/img3.jpg" alt="paper" title="paper" id="wows1_2"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/img4.jpg" alt="quiz" title="quiz" id="wows1_3"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/img5.jpg" alt="www" title="www" id="wows1_4"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="ads"><img src="data1/tooltips/img1.jpg" alt="ads"/>1</a>
<a href="#" title="debug"><img src="data1/tooltips/img2.jpg" alt="debug"/>2</a>
<a href="#" title="paper"><img src="data1/tooltips/img3.jpg" alt="paper"/>3</a>
<a href="#" title="quiz"><img src="data1/tooltips/img4.jpg" alt="quiz"/>4</a>
<a href="#" title="www"><img src="data1/tooltips/img5.jpg" alt="www"/>5</a>
</div></div>
<a class="wsl" href="http://wowslider.com">Auto Slider jQuery by WOWSlider.com v2.4</a>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what "wowslider not animating properly" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the bootstrap rule `img { max-width: 100%; }` is the one responsible.

Add that in your css :

```css
.ws_effect img { max-width: inherit!important; }
```

Comment: i have a similar problem and i managed to solve it using an iframe that embbeds the wowslider_generated_html_page.html which contains the working code. in this way the content/style are kept separeted. of course use this if it isn't affect SEO.